# Android - call class method from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a problem with `TimePickerDialog`.
I use a class that extends `RelativeLayout` it's my own view (`MyViewClass`). In this class I have a button named "Select time" and a `TextView` that displays selected date. After clicking on that button I show mentioned TimePickerDialog using: `mTimePickerFragment.show(((Activity) context).getFragmentManager(), "TAG");` in `MyViewClass`.
`MyViewClass` contains a method named `setTimeLabel()` for setting my TextView.

This is my TimePickerDialog class:

```java
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
private int mHour;
private int mMinute;

public TimePickerDialog mTimePickerDialog;


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (mTimePickerDialog == null) {
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    mTimePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, mHour, mMinute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    return mTimePickerDialog;
}

public static TimePickerFragment newInstance() {
    return new TimePickerFragment();
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
    init(hour, minute);

/* 
I want to call method which update my TextView
*/
}

public void init(int hour, int minute) {
    mHour = hour;
    mMinute = minute;

    if (mTimePickerDialog != null) {
        mTimePickerDialog.updateTime(mHour, mMinute);
    }
}

public int getHour() {
    return mHour;
}

public int getMinute() {
    return mMinute;
}
}
```

All I need is to call method (placed in `MyViewClass`) when time is changed - `onTimeSet()` method. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you familiar with interfaces? They should come in handy for you to call a method in your `TextView` class.

Comment: I know how to use interfaces when fragment is created in activity class and we want to call method that is placed in activity but I don't know how to do that in that case when I sow fragment from my view class and want to call bac method placed in this class.
If you know how to do that pleace help.

Comment: Could you provide additional code for your custom view class?

Comment: @redead I think it's not important. This class extends RelativeLayout. In this class I have a button and textView as I mentioned. When you click on the button I use: mTimePickerFragment.show(((Activity) context).getFragmentManager(), "TAG") to show dialog fragment. There is a method to set the text view in this class as well and I want to be able to call this method from my fragment.

Comment: You could place an `interface` inside your `Fragment` and implement it inside your `CustomView`. Make sure to do this changes on the UIThread. Inside your `CustomView`you can place another interface` to pass events to your activity. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776764/what-is-the-right-way-to-communicate-from-a-custom-view-to-the-activity-in-which)

Comment: @redead I don't need to communicate with activity I just want to call mathod placed in my class (custom view) from the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can set time inside onTimeSet for example if the TimePickerDialog pop up and user selectes the time then it invokes **onTimeSet** Method

```
 @Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
//so you can do anything with the selected time here
//for example
// textViewTime.setText(hour.getText().toString());
// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected Minute"+minute.getText().toString(),Toast.LengthShort);
init(hour, minute);
```

Comment: Yes but TextView is in another class - MyViewClass as I mentioned so how can I call setTextView() (it's placed in my class) method from Fragment?

Comment: @Giks91 Oh.. Is this your full code of this activity? I am not sure but may be you need a Interface to make connection. Please take a  look at Interface to communicate between two fragements. I cannot help you because I don't have good knowledge on Interfaces. ;)

Comment: I know how to use interfaces when we comunicate between activity and fragment but don't know how to do that in this case.

Comment: Do the other stuff here, or do this suff in another activity.

Comment: To sum it up: You have an activity containing a custom view class and you try to update a `TextView` within this class `onTimeSet` with the `TimePicker` being a field of this class?

Comment: Yes There is and activity containing a custom view class. in this class I have a button and textView when you click on the button you see dialog fragment. So I want to call method placed in my class view to update the textView.

Comment: @Giks91 I have answer a timepicker dialog inside your activity without creating a new class for it. I hope this will help you.!!

Comment: @Giks91 you can definately check how it looks before use, I have implemented same code here. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=queendevelopers.com.fakesms

Answer (score 0):

You need not to write these whole stuff, For example, when user clicks a button

```
    new_year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    new_month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    new_day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    new_hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    new_minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
 }
```

"set Time " use this to pick the time.

```
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {
                            _time.setText(hourOfDay+" : "+minute);
                        }
                    }, new_hour, new_minute, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
```

For datePicker

```
   DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            new_year = year;
                            new_month = monthOfYear;
                            new_day = dayOfMonth;
                            _date.setText(new_day+" / "+(new_month+1)+" / "+new_year);
                        }
                    }, new_year, new_month, new_day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
```

You can use new_hour, new_minute, new_day .... beside this in your activity.

Comment: Thanks you are right it's possible but it would be better to keep this code in separate class as I want so I'll try.

Comment: @Giks91 Okay, Post your answer when you'll make it correct. I will learn that how will you do. That will be a helpful. ^_^ .

Comment: Sure so please vote for my question it should help to find good answer.

Comment: @Giks91 Did you find a answer?